# text-align center is not centering text on h1 and h2

Tags: html, css, text, center, text-align

As the title says, I am trying to center h1 and h2. But whenever I type text-align: center; it just pushes them both to the left. I would like to have both h1 and h2 in the direct center of the screen. I could do it manually but I want it to be perfectly center. Thanks :)

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Passion One';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #42E616;
  letter-spacing: 1.6rem;
  top: calc(80% - 200px);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: .68;
  z-index: 2001;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: .4rem ;
  top: calc(58% - 30px);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .68 ;
  z-index: 2002;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="Style.css">

  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title> AL-SABA.net </title>

</head>

<header>
  <h1> Title </h1>

  <h2> Personal Website </h2>
</header>
  
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `position: absolute;`. That removes an element from the normal flow of the DOM and makes the element only as big as it needs to fit the content inside of it. So instead of taking up the entire width of the screen, as block elements like h1 and h2 normally would, they only take up as much space as needed to contain the text inside.

You can make the elements `width: 100%;` or `left: 0; right: 0;` to make them take up the entire width of the page, then `text-align: center;` will work as expected.

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Passion One';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #42E616;
  letter-spacing: 1.6rem;
  top: calc(80% - 200px);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: .68;
  z-index: 2001;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: .4rem ;
  top: calc(58% - 30px);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .68 ;
  z-index: 2002;
}

h1,h2 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="Style.css">

  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title> AL-SABA.net </title>

</head>

<header>
  <h1> Title </h1>

  <h2> Personal Website </h2>
</header>
  
  
</html>
```

Or you can position them 50% from left, then `transform: translateX(-50%);` to push the element back to the left half of it's own width to put it in the center of the page.

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Passion One';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #42E616;
  letter-spacing: 1.6rem;
  top: calc(80% - 200px);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: .68;
  z-index: 2001;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: .4rem ;
  top: calc(58% - 30px);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .68 ;
  z-index: 2002;
}

h1,h2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="Style.css">

  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title> AL-SABA.net </title>

</head>

<header>
  <h1> Title </h1>

  <h2> Personal Website </h2>
</header>
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: @Lukie no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're position them absolute to the parent they're not been forced to move, by removing the position absolute it works perfectly. [Absolute positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Passion One';
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #42E616;
  letter-spacing: 1.6rem;
  top: calc(80% - 200px);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: .68;
  z-index: 2001;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: .4rem ;
  top: calc(58% - 30px);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .68 ;
  z-index: 2002;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="Style.css">

  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title> AL-SABA.net </title>

</head>

<header>
  <h1> Title </h1>

  <h2> Personal Website </h2>
</header>
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this, and for some reason it gives the text a white background behind it. Which wouldnt be a problem but it covers up my websites background.

Comment: Here is a picture: https://gyazo.com/faa9ef5c318feda0f47e3231d5467eb6 this is what it is supposed to look like but with the text centered: https://gyazo.com/5fd0afdd18ba24090a5a11f889312f31